# Как разбить строку?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! 
Имеется строка такого вида:

> `"zz" "zz" 0 0 263.57727 1309080332`

Как мне разбить ее и записать в масив, чтоб получилось:

> `$massiv[0] = zz
> $massiv[1] = zz
> $massiv[2] = 0 
> $massiv[3] = 0
> $massiv[4] = 263.57727
> $massiv[5] = 1309080332`

Нашел функцию : `preg_match_all`, только так и не разобрался, как ее использовать.
Можно как-нибудь по доступнее обьяснить, узучаю php совсем не давно - по этому туговато доходит =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '"доброе дело" "хороший день" 0 0 263.57727 1309080332';
preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"|([\d\.]+)/', $str, $ar);
echo '<pre>';print_r($ar);echo '</pre>';
```

Смотрим, решаем, что делать дальше. ;)

Comment: Отлично то что нужно! можно только прокоментировать вот этот участок кода

'/"([^"]*)"|([\d\.]+)/' что это за символы и что ои зачат здесь

Comment: Конечно, можно. [http://www.phpfaq.ru/regexp][1]

[1]:http://www.phpfaq.ru/regexp

Comment: так как мне через echo вывести все это по отдельности?
если написать echo "$ar"; нечего не выходит.
Как правильно теперь вывести на экран куски строк?

Comment: Опа-на. Погуглите циклы и многомерные массивы в php.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так :)

```
$str = "\"zz\" \"zz\" 0 0 263.57727 1309080332";
$massiv = explode(" ", $pizza);
print_r($massiv);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что присутствуют записи такого рода 
"доброе дело" "хороший день" 0 0 263.57727 1309080332
и получаются отдельные переменные $massiv[0]="доброе  $massiv[0]=дело". А надо чтоб вместе было.

Comment: @ling, я побуду предсказателем: те вылетит нотис, что Пиццы нет. И не будет. и заказать нельзя, даже за деньги. Потому что ты объявил `$str;`

и мне все равно, что пиццу не вычистил пронин. Кто последний правил? =)))